# Erro ao carregar DLL em SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dll

Recebi uma DLL de um cliente, que estará criptografando 4 chaves para serem enviadas em consultas do banco.

Efetuei o registro com  `sp_addextendedproc 'xp_definekey', 'c:\path\criptokey.dll'`. Mas ao executar esta retornando o erro:

> Não é possível carregar a DLL c:\path\criptokey.dll  ou uma das DLLs às quais ela faz referência. Motivo: 193(%1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido.).

Como resolver esse problema?